# Running a Parse Server cloud function at a given route

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, routes, parse-server

I have a Cloud function defined as:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getTravel', function (request, response) {...
```

I can access it at 
http://127.0.0.1:1338/parse/functions/getTravel

I want to version my API and serve it at
http://127.0.0.1:1338/parse/functions/v1/getTravel

I tried to change the definition as follow but it doesn't work:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getTravel', function (request, response) {...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If think the better way to do that is to replace `parse` by the current version of you API

For example when you deploy your parse-server add the version of your API: http://127.0.0.1:1338/v1.0/functions/getTravel

You can do that with the PARSE_MOUNT variable in your env

If you want to have a single instance that run multiple version, just create multiple ParseServer and serve it like that :

```
var v1 = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/v1/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/v1',
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"]
  }
});

var v2 = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/v2/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/v2',
});

app.use('/v1', api);
app.use('/v2', api);
```

Note:
At this level with parse you can't make url like  http://127.0.0.1:1338/parse/functions/v1/getTravel without fork it

Comment: But then I need to run one instance per publicServerURL, right? I want a single instance run multiple versions of the API.

Comment: Ok thanks. Shame proper route support is not implemented.

Comment: @MasterScrat yes you're right, you need to manage that manually

Comment: Why not just create a new route, and call the cloud function from that route in a GET request.

Comment: @GellertLee that's another solution in fact ! But if he need to have different version of afterSave or beforeSave of his Classes, he can't